# Convert Vim colour scheme to Cream?

Tags: vim, gvim

How can I set up Cream to use [Vim's vibrantink colour scheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1794)?

Answer (score 0):

look into the cream-files, escpecially `cream-colors.vim`. scroll down a bit and then add a new block of code (copyNpaste) around line 156:

```
elseif mychoice == "zenburn"
    call Cream_source($CREAM . "cream-colors-zenburn.vim")
    " if called, change selection, too (otherwise don't change)
    if exists("a:1")
         call Cream_colors_selection("zenburn")
    elseif exists("g:CREAM_COLORS_SEL")
         call Cream_colors_selection(g:CREAM_COLORS_SEL)
    endif
else
    let mychoice = "cream"
```

add a new section block and replace "cream-colors-zenburn.vim" with the colorscheme you want. do not forget to put that theme into the cream folder.

then open `cream-menu-settings.vim` and take a look around lines 395:

```
" color schemes (Cream)
if exists("g:CREAM_COLORS") && g:CREAM_COLORS == "cream"
    execute 'anoremenu  60.633 &Settings.P&references.&Color\ Themes.' . s:on . 'Cream\ (default)    :call Cream_colors("cream")'
else
    execute 'anoremenu  60.633 &Settings.P&references.&Color\ Themes.' . s:off . 'Cream\ (default)    :call Cream_colors("cream")'
endif
```

apply the same logic for your theme. that should bring up your color theme up and running in cream.